# Import python packages with different versions installed

Tags: python, installation, package-managers, ubuntu-15.10

I have a problem. I'm trying to install a script written in python. It requires 3.4+ version, and I have python2.7 python3.4 python3.5 installed on my ubuntu 15.10 by default. During setup it throws an error which I found is concerning missing packages in python.

The error is

```
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/distutils/dist.py", line 1209, in set_requires distutils.versionpredicate.VersionPredicate(v)
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/distutils/versionpredicate.py", line 114, in __init__ raise ValueError("expected parenthesized list: %r" % paren) 
ValueError: expected parenthesized list: '-branch'
```

I looked into source, found list of required packages and made a small script which gives me missing ones

```
import pip
installed_packages = pip.get_installed_distributions()
flat_installed_packages = [package.project_name for package in installed_packages]
packages = [
    "aiohttp",
    "httplib2",
    "socksipy-branch",
    "requests",
    "dns",
    "url"
]
for needle in packages:
    if needle in flat_installed_packages:
        print('Found ', needle)
    else:
        print('Not found ', needle)`
```

Output is

```
Found  aiohttp
Found  httplib2
Not found  socksipy-branch
Found  requests
Not found  dns
Found  url
```

I tried to install these with synaptic manager, with manual apt-get, with pip, pip3, pip3.4 but with no luck. As I can see from random messages during package installation it installs them into python 2.7, no matter what I do. How do I get them into 3.4 version? Please help me.

Comment: Use a virtual environment.

Comment: To understand virtual environments, pleease read http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/ .

Comment: you can directly try `python3 -m pip install dns` if you dont want to create a virtualenv. NOTE : virtualenv is really good tool and you should try it anyway

Comment: Thanks for reply guys. Yesterday I tried  to setup virtual environment, but same with no luck, I'll try it again. 
Command "python3 -m pip install dns" doesn't help even if I try "python3 -m pip install dnspython"