# In a python environment, how to import a package from a specific version?

Tags: python, dependency-management, package-managers

**This is not a duplicate of the question:**

[Import python packages with different versions installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35600492/import-python-packages-with-different-versions-installed)

**Nor can it be solved by virtualenv/pipenv**: packages that share the same name/path but has different code/version **must be installed under the same environment for the program to function properly**

Considering the following classic diamond dependency problem:

- program <- feature_A <- library (v 1.0)
- program <- feature_B <- library (v 2.0)

Assuming we have full access over the sourcecode of packages 'program', 'feature_A', and 'feature_B', and both feature_A and feature_B has the following code:

```
import library.*
```

In a conventional package manager like virtualenv, pip and conda, The above situation will preclude feature_A and feature_B from being used in the same project. However since python is an interpretive language, and we can use the source code of feature_A and feature_B. It should be possible to do the following things:

1. ingest the package source/byte codes of both `library (v1.0)` and `library (v2.0)`, generate 2 cryptographic hash for each, and install them under 2 different paths that depends on their respective hashes.
2. use a code generator to rewrite `feature_A` and `feature_B` such that they import from new paths that depends on cryptographic hashes, and install the rewritten versions.
3. use the code generator to rewrite `program` such that it imports from the new paths where the rewritten `feature_A` and `feature_B` are installed.

Now my question is: how difficult it is to fully automate this process? Is a weak artificial intelligence required? Or it can be accomplished using pure functional logic?

Comment: I'll go ahead and ask, `Assuming we have full access over the sourcecode of packages 'program', 'feature_A', and 'feature_B'`... if this is the case why not restructure your code to make your life easier? (for example, `from library.v1 import func as funcv1;from library.v2 import func as funcv2` ?)

Comment: Ok, so looks like you _don't_ have control over `library`, right?  my misunderstanding.

Comment: you could also try to mock the imports when loading the particular features.

Answer (score 3):

I would install the different package versions in different `PYTHONPATH`, e.g.

```sh
PYTHONPATH=insertherepath1 ; python setup.py install --prefix=insertherepath1
```

or

```sh
PYTHONPATH=insertherepath1 ; pip install --install-option="--prefix=insertherepath1" package==v1
```

and the same for the other version of the package to be installed in another path `insertherepath2`. The two installations in different `PYTHONPATH`s still can access other commonly installed packages in the main python path.

To use the different packages within `python`:

```py
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, 'insertherepath1')
import package #gets version 1
#maybe (depends on further dependencies) : sys.path.pop(0)
```

and equivalently to use the other version:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, 'insertherepath2')
import package #gets version 2
#maybe (depends on further dependencies) : sys.path.pop(0)
```

Comment: thanks a lot for the idea! but sys.path is process global, what if 2 imports happens almost simultaneously in 2 threads?

Answer (score 1):

Installing specific versions

pip allows you to specify which version of a package to install using version specifiers. For example, to install a specific version of requests:

`pip install requests==2.18.4`

To install the latest 2.x release of requests:

`pip install requests>=2.0.0,<3.0.0`

To install pre-release versions of packages, use the --pre flag:

`pip install --pre requests`

Comment: this approach seems reasonable for when `pip` is used to manage installations within a particular virtual environment (e.g. with `venv`)

Answer (score 1):

I haven't run into this scenario myself.  My suggestion would be to rename the libraries so they install at different names.  To me that seems like the simplest approach.

Answer (score 0):

python pkg_resources may help you .

```
https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pkg_resources.html#workingset-objects
```